# How do you select records based on their ID number and only if second ID is a specific word

Tags: sql, select, ms-access-2013

I need some help with selecting and displaying specific data.

This is travel data and I only want to find what the first and second trips are, and only if the 2nd trip is `'Home' or 'ReturnFromWork'`. I want to see who made direct trips from Home-to-Activity and Activity-to-Home only. Please help, thank you.

Let's say the table name is called `FlatFare.csv`

```
Sample Data:
Zone   TripNumber  TripPurpose   
----    --------- --------   
1           1       work      
1           2       ReturnFromWork       
1           1       market     
1           2       work
1           3       home
2           1       School
2           2       home

Result:
Zone     TripNumber  TripPurpose
-----     --------    ---------
1            1         work
1            2         ReturnFromWork
2            1         school
2            2         home
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in SQL

```
SELECT Zone, TripNumber, TripPurpose  FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY zone ORDER BY zone) AS RowID, * FROM your_TableName) AS Temp
WHERE RowID <=2
```